# how to read and reinject response data from a http request

Tags: ionic3

I have a global provider where I want to inject all variables needed for my app.

I also have TWO others providers (network and webwservices) that need to interact with this global provider.

My Network provider checks some basic functionality and gets the uuid device. No problem to inject this data in my global Provider. I’m using this data again in my Webservices provider which is used to interact with my Api (get and update data). So I post this data to my Api and get an object response with a token.

I’d like to reinject this token in my global Provider but it doesn’t work. I always get my data undefined in my global Provider.

This is my code :

**webservicesProvider.ts**

```
return this.global.apiToken;
this.http.post(this.url_api + '?action=getToken', dataToPost)
                    .subscribe(data => {
                        console.log(data);

                         console.log(data['status']); 
                        if (data['status']==1){
                            console.log(data['token']);
                            this.global.apiToken = data['token'];

                            console.log(this.global.apiToken);
                        }else{
                            console.log('erreur status');
                        }
```